# Drifting problem in Hector_mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!

Recently, I tried using the hector_slam package for mapping. The Laser which I am using is Hokuyo LiDAR UTM-30LX.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66972/drifting-problem-in-hector_mapping/) by [Edward Ramsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/4814/edward-ramsay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have an IMU in your UAV? hector_slam works well without it (the IMU) as long as you maintain it levelled with the floor. You can make an experiment and move the laser with your hand while tilting it, in an attempt of reproducing the motion of your UAV, to see how good your map becomes...

More info about how hector_slam uses IMU [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/40584/hector_slam-and-imu/)

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1